# how to parse xml with special character in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, xml-parsing

I am getting following error when i add `<` in my xml,

> Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 XML parsing: line 4, character 14,
>   illegal qualified name character

How can i parse xml with these type of special characters?

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>W < hite</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color1,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color2,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color3,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]/@Special','varchar(10)')+' '+
+a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color4,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color5[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color5,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits2,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits3,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Invalid special characters & its substitute in xml

1. & - `&amp;`
2. < - `&lt;`
3. > - `&gt;`
4. " - `&quot;`
5. ' - `&#39;`

Answer (score 10):

`<` needs to be specified as `&lt;` in the XML

```
<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>W &lt; hite</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>
```

**Update:**

The characters you **need** to escape in node values are `<` => `&lt;` and `&` => `&amp;`.
In attribute values you also need to escape `"` => `&quot;` if you use `"` around your attribute values.

This is a valid XML:

```
<root>
  <item> &lt; > &amp; ' "</item>
  <item att=" &lt; > &amp; ' &quot;" />
</root>
```

Try it in a query:

```
declare @xml xml =
'
<root>
  <item> &lt; > &amp; '' "</item>
  <item att=" &lt; > &amp; '' &quot;" />
</root>
'

select @xml.value('(root/item)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as NodeValue,
       @xml.value('(root/item/@att)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as AttValue
```

Result:

```
NodeValue            AttValue
-------------------- --------------------
 < > & ' "            < > & ' "
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure the XML is valid, so you need to make sure any special characters are encoded.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>W &lt; hite</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'
```

Comment: will you provide me, how many speical character xml did not parse, and thier subsitute