# How to upper case xml with special character in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing

I need to upper case a XML, but the xml could have some special characters like < & " so I replace them in the XML with `(&lt;)` `(&amp;)` `(&quot;)`, then when I do the ucase with upper I get this:

`XML parsing: line 1, character 387, well formed check: undeclared entity`

How can avoid this? so I can ucase my XML?

[Parsing xml with Special Characters in SQl Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920792/how-to-parse-xml-with-special-character-in-sql-server)

Comment: You should not treat XML like it's just a string. It makes no sense to "upper case" XML, as you would likely be turning it into invalid XML.

Answer (score 1):

[XML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) must be lower-case. So, you could try upper-casing before encoding the special characters.